# How to add python backend to a Flutter App

Tags: python, android, flutter, backend, flutter-dependencies

I need to run my python script within a flutter app , How can I do it?
I tried importing the python file but it showed error.

Comment: where you tried to import python file?

Comment: anyway, this is what you most likely need: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process-class.html

Comment: I tried using import 'code.py';

Comment: Port your code to dart if possible. You can't use `Process.run` when executing python command on android except you somehow bundle the py interpreter in your app so `Process.run` will mostly likely fail on any platform that doesn't have python in it.

Comment: thats gonna be hard ig, I mean like there should be some way to do this right??/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following blog similar to your use case.
https://smazee.com/blog/how-to-run-the-python-code-in-the-flutter-app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Smazee post above uses Starflut. If it matter to you, Starflut claims to be open source but, in fact, [is not open source](https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter/issues/27).